# Align background image in HTML link / button

Tags: html, css, less

It's quite difficult to explain without some *visual reference* so if you look at the screenshot here:

[image]

You see a button that I've created. Just a normal old link tag with some styling added to it. Now that little arrow you see? That's a background property and I just for the life of me can't get it positioned *preeeety much* in the vicinity of that ghastly pink dot I've drawn on.

To have a look at the code, instead of posting all of it here, have a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/Relborg/pen/kDnre) that Ive created. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `background-position: 10px center;`

Comment: Gasp!! That's it! Thank you very much! i tried something similiar though. background-position: 10px 10px; and that didn't do a single thing? Why is that...?

Comment: @Relborg that should have changed it's X position 10px and Y position 10px. (By the way, I found out why nothing was showing for me in your CodePen :P)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
background-position: 10px center;
```

I've modified your [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CIzvw).

Comment: 2mins behind @jan reimers, but heck, I'll give you the upvote :D

Comment: Usually it tells you when an answer has been posted, ah well he got there first! :)